# DOM related question and problem

Tags: python, dom

these day im making python script related with DOM.

problem is these day many website structure is very complicate .

what is best method to check DOM structure and path..

i mean...following is some example.

what is best method to check  can extract such like following info quickly?

before i was spent much time to extract such info .

and yes im also new to python and DOM.

```
IE.Document.Frames(1).Document.forms('comment').value = 'hello'
```

if i use DOM inspector, can i extract such info quickly ? if so would you show me some sample?

here is some site . i want to extract some dom info.

today i was spent all day long to extract what is dom info. but failed

http://www.segye.com/Articles/News/Politics/Article.asp?aid=20091118001261&ctg1=06&ctg2=00&subctg1=06&subctg2=00&cid=0101010600000

at the end of this page,can find some comment input box.

i want to know what kind of dom element should have to use, such like

```
IE.Document.Frames(1).Document.forms('comment').value = 'hello'
```

anyhelp much appreciate thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would hope that you've read [Python's implementation of the DOM](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html) and [here's a good tutorial](http://www.boddie.org.uk/python/XML_intro.html). Alternatively, if you know javascript jQuery makes it incredibly easy to DOM parse and manipulate the DOM, as seen [here](http://www.slideshare.net/remy.sharp/dom-scripting-toolkit-jquery). Now if you're just trying to get someone to parse it for you, good luck.